# Is "Call me when you are available to talk" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> Call me when you are available to talk

Is that correct? Can I use it that way?

Answer (score 21):

Yes.

That is a grammatically correct phrase. Whether or not you should use it depends on your intended meaning. The phrase "Call me when you are available to talk" implies that you want someone to call you once their situation allows it. The wording sounds a bit formal, but it would be acceptable in just about any situation.

If you want to express that they need to call you as soon as possible, you would say just that: "Call me as soon as possible" or "Call me as soon as you can".

If your request is not urgent, then you could say "Call me whenever you get the chance" or "Call me whenever you can".

---

It's also worth noting that if you mean to request that someone return your call, you would usually say "Call me back".

Comment: "Call me when you're free" or "Call me when you get a minute" would also work well here when there's a more informal setting - eg when you know the person. "Call me when convenient" is a better phrase for a business setting

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on a number of factors, such as how well you know the other person.

***A few other comments that I hope will be helpful:***

It rarely hurts to start off such a request with *please*:

> Please call me when you have some time.

As far as the "to talk" at end goes, that's a tricky one. In one sense, it's almost implied, so you don't really need it:

> Please call me when you are available.

I'd probably leave off the "to talk" with that wording, but if I changed my wording, I might be more inclined to leave those two words in:

> Please call me when you have enough time to talk.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additional thoughts:

- If I want you to tell me the number of widgets the store has sold today,
  I might use “[Please] call me whenever you can”,
  or one of the other shorter, less formal phrases.

  Of course, if that’s *all* I need from you,
  I would probably leave a message saying
  “[Please] let me know how many widgets the store has sold today.”
- If I want you to explain why widgets are selling so poorly
  compared to gizmos, and to discuss ideas
  about what we can do to improve (increase) the sales of widgets,
  I might use “[Please] call me when you are available to talk”
  as a way of indicating that the conversation might be a long one,
  and you should wait until you know that you will be available
  for a longer chunk of time than the “42 widgets” conversation would require.
- If there’s a new employee in the store
  and I want to ask you how he or she is performing,
  I might use “[Please] call me when you are available to talk”
  as a way of indicating that the conversation might be a sensitive one
  (containing personal information),
  and you should call from a place where you have some privacy
  (so your half of the discussion won’t be overheard).

Whether the above are likely to be applicable depends on the context
and the relationship between the person sending the message and the recipient.